# Install SQL Server 2000 on virtual machine Windows Server 2008 (HyperV)

Tags: sql-server, installation

My hierarchy ask me to setup a production Windows server 2008 virtual machine (HyperV) with SQL 2000 Standard Ed. installed on it.

I can't find on the net much information about the relative "compatibility" of SQL2000 on WinSrv2008.
Of course I found some obscure answers like : "it's impossible, it's not supported, don't do it".

I already setup the machine, it's working, but... I don't know where I'm going.

Do you experienced this kind of configuration ?
Could you give me some advices ? 
Could you tell me the pros and cons ?

Thanks a lot for you help

Comment: It may run, but it's not supported.  That means that if it breaks, you're on your own.

Comment: It's still working well on windows Server 2012

Comment: Yeah, there's a difference between "doesn't work" and "isn't supported."

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft doesn't support SQL 2000 on Windows 2008 but that doesn't mean it won't work (as you've already found out). Of course, you could get it into production and then find some odd quirk that affects availability after the fact and if you called Microsoft about it, they wouldn't help much.

All that having been said, you said you're running this as a VM so the fact that the host server is running Windows 2008 has no impact on the operating system running in the virtual machine hosting SQL 2000. If it were me, I'd create a Windows 2003 R2 virtual machine and install SQL 2000 there so you have a supported and known-good configuration.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2000 run on Windows Server 2008 (HyperV VM).

That's the configuration we have at the moment.

Although you can find on Internet that this is not suported, i can tell you that runs correctly and, using a litle tricky steps, you can still design and execute the SQL Server 2000 DTS from the Legacy folder on Management Studio 2008.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1db097b0-fd11-4a87-a265-b91bb1c08e53/dts-in-sql-server-management-studio-2008?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Have a nice day